# Is there a reliable way to learn if a video file is valid? VideoPlayer does not detect empty/small size files as invalid ones

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, video-player

I need to detect if video file is valid(and delete it if it is not). It is an air application.

For large files it can be accomplished by processing `MediaPlayerState.PLAYBACK_ERROR` state. No problems.

---

However, when there's an **empty file** like `empty.mp4`, it does not dispatch any PLAYBACK_ERROR. 
Then I created a file singleChar.mp4 (with `x` letter inside), the behavior was exactly the same.

It goes through `READY` state without any problems.  `playing` is true at that time (it is said in the documentation that it is `true` when it is `playing or attempting to play`, so this is also not reliable).

Then I suggested that it treats those files as valid ones with `duration=0`... No! Duration is not set, `durationChange` is not dispatched.

The best approach for now is to `play()` it, `setTimeout` for about `50ms` and check `duration` when this timeout expires. At least it works in 50% cases. However, this is completely **unreliable**. Reliability may be improved by extending the delay, but I'd prefer to detect it quickly and handle silently before user will notice any problems.

Other possible approach is to check if the file is less than some size(maybe,100KB?), however, this is also another stupid unreliable approach.

**So, is there a reliable way to detect if a file is a valid video file?**